# Не выходит окно для выбора аккаунта google

Tags: android, kotlin, auth

Пытался внедрить google регистрацию , вот код:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val btn: View = findViewById<View>(R.id.sign_in_button)

        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build()
        val mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            signIn(mGoogleSignInClient)
        }
    }

    private fun signIn(mGoogleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient) {
        val signInIntent: Intent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 123)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == 123) {

            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            Log.d("MyLog", task.toString())
            handleSignInResult(task)
        }
    }

    private fun handleSignInResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {

                val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            Log.d("MyLog", account.idToken.toString())

        } catch (e: ApiException) {

            Log.d("MyLog", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode)

        }
    }
}
```

Зарегал приложение в google cloud :[image]

После добавления проекта в google cloud  при нажатие на кнопку регистрации не выходит окно для выбора аккаунта. В логе `account.idToken.toString()` выводит `null`.

Comment: На некоторых эмуляторах с этим проблема есть. На физическом девайсе тоже не работает?

Comment: Я пробовал на физическом устройстве, не помогло (

Comment: Вообще эта проблема появилась после добавления приложения в Google cloud